# Copy to clipboard or save to file substitution command

Tags: regular-expression, command-line, cut-copy-paste, substitute

I'm trying to answer a [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) question in U&L, which involves a very complex and long regex substitution.

I would like to copy to clipboard *the command*, or save it in a file, so I don't have to make a transcription, prone to errors.

Example:

```
foo
bar
~
~
:s/foo/bar/ ← command to copy
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks! This is my second question though :)

Comment: Hm, doesn't look like it on your profile (not counting deleted questions…), so that could be why it showed up in Review. No worries, keep asking questions! (and maybe answering them!)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The question was off- topic :| maybe that's the reason it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To past the content of a register you can prefix your `p` command with `"[register_name]`, that's what `["x]` mean in `["x]p` in [`:h p`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#p):

```
                            p
["x]p       Put the text [from register x] after the cursor
            [count] times.
```

You command is stored in the `:` register: If you want to put it in a buffer you can do <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, and after that you can handle it like any text in any register.

Comment: What I usually do is after testing a vim command, copying it to the clipboard in order to paste it into stackexchange. So *after* running the vim ex command, storing it in the clipboard using `:let @+=@:`

Comment: Good way to do it indeed. Personnaly I prefer to confirm what I'm doing by pasting in a scratch buffer but your version is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If the command you wanted to copy wasn't the last one, it can be helpful to open the command-line window with `q:` or `:<C-f>`. Then you can do, e.g., `"*yy` or `:yank +` or however you prefer.

(Personally, I use my [pbcopy](https://github.com/benknoble/vimpbcopy) plugin to yank to the clipboard with `<C-y>`; mapping is configurable, though it does always use the `*` register.)